# How can i find route link in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, routes

> Hi, i am beginner in laravel i got a project where users can do bitcoin trading, When i am hitting mydomain/admin it's working fine but when user is registering his account and getting redirected to user dashboard 500 internal server error is throwing. after alot of research i found a route which is passing to dashboard user.home but i can't find it in any file so that i see if routing link is wrong can anyone guide me about how can i find where user.home route is created ?

I have tried alot of solutions but still can't get out of this trouble

Comment: Can you show us a sample of your code? And what kind of solutions you have tried?

Answer (score 1):

You can find the list of your project's route in routes folder > web.php
[see this image for detail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l8OHz.png)

and you can simply search for the route you need.
hope this help